# How to Get value of select onChange in Functional Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

Im Using ant design pro with react to create form, but i cannot save the value of select using hooks. i Shows a errorn error[image]

```
const ExistingGroup = (props) => {
  const [group,setGroup] = useState([]);

  const saveGroup = (event) => {
    setGroup(event.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <PageContainer header={{ title: '' }} ghost>
      <Card bordered={false} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Form>
          <Form.Item>
            <Select value={group} onSelect={saveGroup}>
              <Option value='1'>1</Option>
              <Option value='2'>2</Option>
            </Select>
            {group}
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Card>
    </PageContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: You may have meant `onChange` rather than `onSelect`? Since [The select event only fires after text inside an `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>` is selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselect).

Comment: Whoops. I completely forgot that react props != DOM events. Please feel free to ignore my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation of [`Select`](https://ant.design/components/select/#API), the `onSelect` method is called with the value of the selected element.

> `onSelect`    Called when an option is selected, the params are option's value (or key) and option instance
> `function(string | number | LabeledValue, option: Option)`

so you want

```
const saveGroup = (value) => {
  setGroup(value);
}
```

---

Also, since it is not multiselect, you should use a single value for the `group` and not an array.

```
const [group,setGroup] = useState(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solved my problem.